# I want to create a real-time facial expression analysis app, but the camera feed is not appearing on the screen

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to create an app using Flask that does the following:

- When the app is launched, it activates the device's camera.
- It analyzes the faces captured by the camera using Py-Feat to evaluate real-time emotions.

However, when I run the app in the console, the camera feed doesn't appear on the screen. There are no specific error messages in the console, and I have no idea how to resolve this issue. In the terminal, I see something like "weights=None," so I suspect it might be related.

Does anyone have any good ideas or suggestions on how to solve this?
Reference code
flask_AIface.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
import numpy as np
import cv2
from feat import Detector
# rf: https://py-feat.org/content/intro.html#available-models
face_model = "retinaface"
landmark_model = "mobilenet"
au_model = "svm"
emotion_model = "resmasknet"
detector = Detector(
    face_model=face_model,
    landmark_model=landmark_model,
    au_model=au_model,
    emotion_model=emotion_model
)


app = Flask(__name__)

cap_cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')  # ここではindex.htmlというテンプレートをレンダリングします。


def gen():
    # ここに、カメラからフレームを取得し、それを処理するコードを書く。
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap_cam.read()
        if not ret:
            print('Error reading frame from camera')
            continue
        if len(frame.shape) == 2:
            frame = np.stack((frame,) * 3, axis=-1)
        else:
            frame = frame[:, :, ::-1]
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = detector.detect_faces(gray)

        for face in faces:
            bbox = face.bbox.astype(int)
            emotion = detector.detect_emotion(face)
            cv2.putText(frame, emotion, (bbox[0], bbox[1] - 10),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, (36, 255, 12), 2)

        ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + jpeg.tobytes() + b'\r\n\r\n')


@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')  # MJPEG形式でストリーミングします。


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # すべてのインターフェイスからのアクセスを許可し、デバッグモードで実行します。
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5001, debug=True)
```

index.html

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Real-Time Face Emotion App</title>
    <link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon">
</head>

<body>
    <img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}" width="640" height="480">
</body>

</html>
```

① The "favicon not found 404" error occurred. Could that be the cause? → Already resolved (created a favicon).
② I'm getting an "Error reading frame from camera" in the Warp while running. Should I try changing the camera number specified in cv2? → Already resolved (confirmed that the built-in camera works with "cap_cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)").
③ Could it be due to interference from a Chrome extension? → Already addressed (turned off the extensions).
④ Console: "Can't read 3D image with 2D axis. Install numpy and support 3D!" Me: "Okay, I installed numpy!" Console: "You don't have numpy installed!" Me: "Uh..." This is currently the most likely hypothesis, but I haven't found a solution yet.

Development Environment:

- VSCode
- MacBook Air M1
- iPad Pro 12.9-inch (used as an extended display)[Screen shot 1[Screen shot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qtpB.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCf23.png)